# How to make library for linked-list functions

Tags: c, struct, static-libraries

I want to create static or dynamic library for linked list functions, but when I try to compile function files with `gcc` to get object file it gives me error `‘struct node’ declared inside parameter list
 int GetNth(struct node* head, int index)` & `dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct node’ if(i == index) return head->data;`. Not sure what's going on, may be because I haven't declared the `structure` in the file

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int count(struct node* head, int n) //counts the occurrence of n in the list
{
  int c = 0;
  while(head != NULL){
    if(head->data == n) c+=1;
    head = head->next;
  }
  return c;
}
```

But if I'll declare it inside this file, I think it'll violate 1 definition rule. What to do?
structure is declared in the main function as

```
struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing _{}_ in your if statement

Comment: @CIsForCookies He's not, it's just dreadfully formatted on a single line with equally bad indentation afterward.

Comment: _"may be because I haven't declared the structure in the file"_ Yes, exactly. How is the compiler meant to know what `struct node` looks like if you don't give it the necessary information?

Comment: Put the `struct` definition and the function prototype in a header file, if you are making a library. That header file is included by the calling code and the library code.

Comment: But if I'll declare it in this file.. it'll violate 1 definition rule, coz it's already declared in the calling function..

Comment: @WhozCraig I think OP meant to have _head = head->next_ inside the if statement.

Comment: @WeatherVane give me an example plz

Comment: @CIsForCookies I sincerely hope not, as that would be an infinite loop unless the list was empty or every node in the list held the value `n`.

Comment: @surjit If it's declared somewhere you need to include that declaration. Else, the compiler will generate errors

Comment: For examples, have a look at your standard library.

Comment: standard library doesn't have library files for data structures like linked-list

Comment: @CIsForCookies Can you tell me how to include that declaration.. I'm not getting it..

Comment: @surjit look at your posted code. Now with *just that*, ask yourself, how does the compiler know `struct node` has a member called `data`? (hint the only correct answer here is, "it doesn't", and that's the problem; you haven't told it as much). My crystal ball tells me you're trying to craft a *generic* linked list library that could be used for *any* user-defined structures and host them in a linked list of your own devices. Is that the case?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes you are right

Comment: @surjit That's a tall order, and a lot more involved than you may think.

Comment: @WhozCraig tell me

Comment: I think it may *sound* like what you want, but I don't think it is what you need, or are prepared to write. Believe me, it would be a lot more work than its worth.

Comment: You simply need a declaration, e.g. `struct node { int data; struct node *next; };` to tell the compiler what a `node` is. You can include this in a header file, or from an encapsulating standpoint, declare it in this file if it is only use within this source file. You can also create a convenient `typedef` for `node`, e.g. `typedef struct node { int data; struct node *next; } node;`

Comment: @WhozCraig it's worth learning..

Comment: I would do what David just described to solve the immediate problem at hand. You can always take up generic-library-writing later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, in your code, the compiler does not know what `node` is because you have not provided its *declaration*. You can provide a declaration including a `typedef` for convenience. The following code declares a `typedef` to `struct _node {...}` as `node;` and then declares two nodes (statically for simplicity reasons), iterates over the list, outputting the `data` values and then ends, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _node {
    int data;
    struct _node *next;
} node;

int main (void) {

    node n1 = {.data = 1}, 
         n2 = {.data = 2, .next = NULL};
    n1.next = &n2;

    /* iterate over list outputting data values */
    for (node *n = &n1; n != NULL; n = n->next)
        printf ("%d\n", n->data);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/llstatic
1
2
```

As mentioned, you can create a header file for your list and include your declaration of `struct _node` and the `typedef` there, or if you simply use `node` within this source-file, you can declare it here. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to using objects (you use it, when have access to its members) you must completely define them. So, to use `struct node`, declare it before its first appearance in the source code. It's the rule of C programming language.

Put the declarations into header file and include the file into source files if you want to create useful libraries, e.g.:

```
...
struct node
{
    ...
};

int count(struct node *head, int n);
...
```

Comment: In that way structure will be defined two times, as it's already defined in the main function.. Is it possible to declare it as `extern`

Comment: You should remove the definition of `struct node` from the main function. You may not apply `extern` to structure definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler tells you it does not recognize `struct node`. You need to Declare it first. Something like `struct node;` (*decleration*) or `struct node{...};` (*definition*) and the error should go away. If you have already declared it in another file `header.h`, just add `#include "header.h"` in the start of your code

Since you want `struct node` to contain a field called `data`, you need to add it when you define the struct:

```
struct node{
    int data;
}
```

Comment: What if it's defined in another function like `main`

Comment: move the definition to a header file and include it in every place it's used would be a clean solution